# Extract multiple values in quotations from the same string of text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I would like to create a formula to grab all text within a string of text /sentence of a field. For example, I have the following text

> Set custom property 'text1' with value '4' for Nexus 2000 Series
>   Fabric Extender 2248TP 'DNS Name' at 'Location'.

I found a formula that can grab the first string in quotes which is

```
=MID(A1,FIND("'",A1)+1,FIND("'",A1,FIND("'",A1)+1)-FIND("'",A1)-1)
```

However, it only extracts the first word in quotes in the sentence/string of text and I need to extract all four strings in quotes. I am hoping to place each word in quotes in a separate column.

Comment: [Ask here you are at wrong community](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: @MuneebAhmed Read: [Are Excel formulas on topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261875/are-excel-formulas-on-topic)

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs thanksf for the link. next time i will take care of this

Answer (score 1):

With your original string in A1 use this in B1 then fill right;

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(CHAR(39)&$A1, CHAR(39), REPT(" ", LEN($A1))), (COLUMN(A:A))*2*LEN($A1), LEN($A1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you all so much. This worked perfectly for my purposes.